# A better django datetime filter at the admin panel

Tags: django, django-admin

Greetings,
I would like to know if there is any already developed plugin for Django admin to have a better filter for the given date/datetime to filter between the given date interval instead of "today", "last week" etc..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a look at my [split date-time widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622341/is-there-a-selectdatetime-widget-for-django-forms/6625142#6625142). It provides a text input for the date, which you can attach a JavaScript date picker to, and two drop-downs for hours and minutes. The hours can be 12 or 24 hour based.